# Check make dependencies through a static library

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm building multiple executable files using make on linux.  Each executable has it's own folder own small makefile that includes a shared makefile.rules.  So to build the projects I call each makefile individually with a parent makefile.

Like this:

```
# Find Makefiles
MKFLS += $(subst Makefile,,$(shell find */ -name Makefile ))

# Standard build rules, pass down to subordinate make files
all debug install: tags
    @$(foreach folder,$(MKFLS), $(MAKE) -C $(folder) $@ || exit;)
```

I put shared code in a static library.  Each also has it's own folder and makefile.  I am making dependencies when building both the executable and static libraries for the exe or lib with:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -MMD -MP -o $@ $<
```

Then including the generated  files (for just that exe or lib):

```
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

Now I want to ensure the executable file builds if one of the library's source or internal header files change.  I tried including the library's generated .d files, but that didn't work.

First each executable make file defines the static library and where it's built:

```
# My Libraries
LOCALLIBS += $(UTILSLIB)/libone.a
LIBSRC += $(UTILSDIR)/onelib
LOCALLIBS += $(UTILSLIB)/libtwo.a
LIBSRC += $(UTILSDIR)/twolib
```

Then in the Global Rules Makefile that is included:

```
# Rules For Library Dependencies
# Include library dependencies if they exist
-include $(shell find $(LIBSRC) -name \*.d )

# Rule to make libraries that are part of this source tree
$(LOCALLIBS):
    $(foreach folder,$(LIBSRC), $(MAKE)-C $(folder) $(MAKECMDGOALS) || exit;)
    @touch $(LOCALLIBS)
```

I don't think the dependencies follow through the static library.  So even if the libone.a gets built, the executable doesn't.  A second run of the make will be required.  I could try to get my executable to depend on the objects from my libone.a, but now my makefiles are getting messy and complicated.

So.... Is there a way to fix this?  What's the right way to do this?

Comment: *"I want to ensure the executable file builds if one of the library's source or internal header files [changes]."* Really? Even if the executable doesn't depend on that source file or header file?

Comment: Based on my understanding of the dependencies in the *.d files make is just looking at dependencies between files.  If make examines the library dependencies and decides the library needs to be rebuilt, then I likely want the executable built.  Make is comparing dependencies at the file level so it won't know whether there's real dependency beyond the chain of file dependencies.  The build is pretty quick

Comment: I'll take all that as a "yes".

Answer (score 0):

To get the result you're asking for, you must give Make prerequisite lists for the object files, the libraries and the executables.

You already have a method for the object files. You generete dependency list files:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -MMD -MP -o $@ $<
```

and then include them:

```
-include $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
```

So far, so good. (I'll assume that this already works correctly-- you haven't given us enough of your makefiles to test it.)

This approach will *not* work for the libraries. It works for object files because the source files contain lists of header files (as `#include` directives) and the compiler (`$(CC)`) knows how to convert them into prerequisite lists. The library-building tool (`$(AR)`, or whatever you're using) has no such files to read and no way to build such lists. But no matter; for each library, you must specify the list of things you want in it *somehow,* so your library rule ought to look something like this:

```
libone.a: alpha.o beta.o
    $(AR) -cvq $@ $^.    # or whatever you use
```

That takes care of the libraries. Now the executables. Suppose you have an executable `prime` that requires code from `alpha` and `gamma`. The rule will look something like this:

```
prime: gamma.o libone.a
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^.    # or whatever you use
```

That's it. The executable `prime` does not depend on `gamma.h`; if you change `gamma.h`, Make will notice that `gamma.o` is out of date, and therefore so is `prime`. And `prime` does not depend on `alpha.h`; if you change `alpha.h`, Make will notice that `alpha.o` is out of date, and therefore so is `libone.a`, and therefore so is `prime`.

(Further improvements may be possible, once you get this much working.)